# set "stickness on TCP connection" in loadbalancer on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, vpc

I'm scaling up TCP service on AWS now. I investigated for a while and find
"sticky sessions" is using cookie to attach all requests from one user to specific instance via HTTP protocol. However, for TCP connection, is there any solution to open up "stickness" in TCP connection?

Very Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. AWS does not provide any mechanism for TCP sticky sessions. That's the price you pay for being deeper in the network stack.